# Fullcalendar get the date and time & stepper

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, fullcalendar

I am working on a project using FullCalendar, and I work with a stepper.
First step: selecting a time / date (calendar)
Second step: a detail of the date and time selected as well as the resource (here a coach)
Third step: payment

I can recover the date, time and resource when I click

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view, resources) {

            alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
            alert('Clicked on: ' + resources.title);
        }
```

But, how can I get the date and time in step 1 and send it to step 2? And so on ?

Thank you

```
***Edit :*** 
@ADyson Hello, I still have a question. I'm trying to send the resource I'm clicking, but I have errors that appear 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'. I can recover the date and time but not the resource

    `$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
                    url: "/booking/test",
                    data: { dateClicked: date.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM'), resourcesClicked: resources },
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('Data send to the back-end !')
                        $('#modalDateAndTime').html(date.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS'));
                        $('#modalCoach').html(resources.title);
                        $('#fullCalModal').modal();

                        return false;
                    }
                })`



`app.post('/booking/test', function (req, res) {
  const dateClick = req.body.dateClicked;
  const resourceClick = req.body.resourcesClicked;
  console.log("Date: " + dateClick);
  console.log("Coach: " + resourceClick);
  res.render('booking/calendar', {
    dateClick
  })

});`
```

Thank you

Comment: "how can I get the date and time"... firstly "dayClick" will never return you a time, only a date. If you want to allow users to select a specific time, then 1) make sure you're using the "agenda" style view which shows times, and 2) use the "select" callback instead which allows the user to click-and-drag to choose a specific period of time. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting

Comment: "how can i...send it to step 2?"...well I can see you know how to get the relevant variables from the callback, so all you have to do now is call some other function which starts your next step, and pass it those variables in the function call. Maybe it's like `showModal(start, end, resourceID);` or something like that. It's up to you. But basically you pass the data round via function calls just like any other piece of code you would ever write. I'm not really sure what your exact difficulty is? Can you clarify? Have you tried something and encountered a problem?

Comment: Hello, yeap, I use the calendar"agenda" style view. Users can just click on a time range (1h) here is an example
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/21/2/1526989213-capture-d-ecran-2018-05-22-a-13-39-57.png

but I have no idea how to pass the information from step 1 to 2 :-/

Comment: In fact, it would be rather to recover the data clicked and to be able to display them in my view
 (sorry, English is not my first language)

Comment: well I've already told you: You have to pass the relevant variables to your "next step", containing the time range and resource which was chosen. I don't know how you start this "step", but presumably you call a function of some sort?

Comment: Not precisely, I am a little lost. My idea would be to retrieve the date and time, then go to step 2 for a detail (and display the time and time of step 1) and then validate and move to payment. For the stepper, I just use a plugin named "SmartWizard" but I have not set it yet.

Comment: well, however this wizard plugin moves from step to step, then within the fullCalendar "dayclick" or "select" callback (your choice), then you have to interact with that smartwizard and provide the data from fullCalendar to it. I don't know how your plugin works so I can't advise you any more than that. You get the data from the calendar, you trigger the next step in the wizard, and at the same time (or possibly with a separate call depending on the wizard's API), you pass the data to the wizard, and then the wizard does whatever it does.

Comment: Thank you Adyson, you gave me another good idea: the 'modal'. I just tried to send the data to my modal:
`dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view, resources) {
                $('#modalTitle').html(date.format());
                $('#modalBody').html(resources.title);
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                return false;
            }, ` and it's most simple for a beginner like me
 ! haha